# asp.net mvc posting a link

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<a href="<%=Url.Action("Link",new {Letter="All"}) %>" id="All" class="block">ALL</a>
```

Is it possible to post the above link by some means and post a dropdown value to the controller? I want to do this when the Java script is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a form using `Html.BeginForm(...)` and use `POST`.

Inside the form, you can add whatever form fields you need. That form can then be posted using a simple submit button. That will work even if Javascript is disabled.

Comment: so it is not possible to post the link without javascript?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to issue a HTTP POST request using an HTML Anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

### Posting links?

What do you mean by *post a link*?

Links make it possible to make new web requests and are not posted back to server. If your link URL is correctly generated it will point to the correct controller action while also providing your additional variable so action will be able to use it.

And **to make it clear** links work without Javascript. **But** they always issue HTTP GET requests. So when you're after HTTP POST requests you will have to create a form and use a submit button to make a POST request:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Link", new { Letter = "A" })) { %>
    <button type="submit">All</button>
<% } %>
```

This will also work without Javascript.